# Can't use props from parent component in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to send `props` from parent component to child component. I want to use this in `componentDidMount()` at  child component. But it can't get this value. It can get this in `render()` although.

parent component code:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    // fetch with redux
    this.props.fetchItem(id);
  }

  renderItem() {
    const { item } = this.props;
    console.log("item", item);
    // item exists
    return <Child item={item} />
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       {this.renderItem()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

child component code:

```
class Child extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { item } = this.props;
    console.log("item", item);
    // item doesn't exist
  }

  render() {
    console.log("item", item)
    // item exists
    return (
      <p>{item.name}</p>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you're actually rendering the child, so we can see how/if you're passing through the props

Comment: I don't see `renderItem` returning anything, is this pseudocode?

Comment: It doesn't look like `<Parent />` is rendering `<Child />` at all, let alone rendering it with the `item` prop. You should have something like `<Child item={this.props.item} />` in `<Parent />`'s `render()`.

Comment: Sorry I don't know why but `<Child />` is deleted... I have updated this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass props to a child component, this is how you would do it.

```
import MyChildComponent from './itspath'; // import your child component

class Whatever extends React.Component {
    const name = "Bob";      // Pay attention this variable we will pass as props

    <MyChildComponent name={name} />   // Here name is now a prop
}
export default Whatever;
```

Now to use the props. You do not need a class to use the props, but since that is what you were trying.

```
class MyChildComponents extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
  const propsSent  = this.props.name;
  console.log(propsSent);     // This will get you the prop name with a value of Bob
}
}
```